# How to get single record instead of recordset

Tags: odoo, qweb, odoo-12

I'm trying to figure out how to tell my module to display the only one possible (due to the given `_sql_constraint`) related `tag` for a given product (template) in the website (eCommerce product page) in Odoo.

Given the model below, (obviously I need to say) I'm getting an `Expected singleton: woa.website.sale.partner.product.tag(1, 2, 3, ...)` error once there is more than one partner having a tag set for a particular product. However, I'm unable to understand how to get the relation between a certain product (i.e. the product page an user is currently looking at) and the partner itself (i.e. the currently logged in website user).

Model:

```
class WoaWebsiteSalePartnerProductTag(models.Model):
    _name = "woa.website.sale.partner.product.tag"
    _description = "Allow partners to tag products individually for easier search and reference"

    product_id = fields.Many2one('product.template', string='Product', required=True)
    partner_id = fields.Many2one('res.partner', string='Customer', required=True)
    company_id = fields.Many2one('res.company', string='Company', required=False, default=lambda self: self.env.user.company_id)
    tag = fields.Char(string='Product tag given by the partner', required=True, default=False)

    _sql_constraints = [
        ('unique_code', 'unique(product_id, partner_id, company_id)',
         'You can define only one tag per product.'),
    ]


class WoaProductTemplate(models.Model):
    _inherit = "product.template"
    woa_website_sale_partner_product_tag_product_ids = fields.One2many('woa.website.sale.partner.product.tag', 'product_id')


class WoaPartnerTemplate(models.Model):
    _inherit = "res.partner"
    woa_website_sale_partner_product_tag_partner_ids = fields.One2many('woa.website.sale.partner.product.tag', 'partner_id')
```

View:

```
<template id="woa_website_sale_partner_product_tag.product" inherit_id="website_sale.product">
    <xpath expr="//div[@id='product_details']" position="after">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-xl-4 offset-xl-2" id="woa_website_sale_partner_product_tag.product.tag">
            <t t-if="request.env.user.active == True">
                <b>Your reference for this product:</b>
                <t t-if="product.woa_website_sale_partner_product_tag_product_ids.partner_id.id == request.env.user.partner_id.id">
                    <span t-field="product.woa_website_sale_partner_product_tag_product_ids.tag"/>
                </t>
            </t>
        </div>
    </xpath>
</template>
```

I'm quite sure that this is the point where `@api.one` and some sweet method actually defining the relation between the product and partner comes in but I don't get how this method is supposed to look like and actually called in the template.

Error message:

```
Error to render compiling AST
ValueError: Expected singleton: woa.website.sale.partner.product.tag(5, 6)
Template: 1492
Path: /templates/t/t[4]/div/section/div[2]/div[3]/t[1]
Node: <t t-if="product.woa_website_sale_partner_product_tag_product_ids.partner_id.id == request.env.user.partner_id.id">
                        <span t-field="product.woa_website_sale_partner_product_tag_product_ids.tag"/>
                    </t>
```

---

A computed field (like given below) which does the `search()` and return that one record I'm looking for is probably the way to go:

```
partner_product_tag = fields.Char('woa.website.sale.partner.product.tag', compute='partner_product_tag', store=False)

@api.one
def partner_product_tag(self):
    partner_product_tag = request.env['woa.website.sale.partner.product.tag'].search([('product_id', '=', self.product_id), ('partner_id', '=', self.partner_id), ('company_id', '=', self.company_id)])
    return partner_product_tag
```

But, how am I supposed to put this into my module and what would the relevant template section than look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, using a computed field *is* the way.

In addition I think it's worth mentioning that `return`ing from the compute method is not a good idea as it won't actually give back the desired value, `self.woa_website_sale_partner_product_tag = ...` however does.

So my working `WoaProduct` class looks like this now:

```
class WoaProduct(models.Model):
    _inherit = "product.template"
    woa_website_sale_partner_product_tag_product_ids = fields.One2many('woa.website.sale.partner.product.tag', 'product_id')
    woa_website_sale_partner_product_tag = fields.Char('woa.website.sale.partner.product.tag', compute='_partner_product_tag', store=False)

    @api.one
    def _partner_product_tag(self):
        user = self.env.user
        product_id = int(self.id)
        partner_id = user.partner_id.id
        company_id = user.company_id.id
        #return woa_website_sale_partner_product_tag ## DON'T!
        self.woa_website_sale_partner_product_tag = http.request.env['woa.website.sale.partner.product.tag'].search([('product_id', '=', product_id), ('partner_id', '=', partner_id), ('company_id', '=', company_id)]).tag ## DO THIS INSTEAD
```

... and the related template looks as following:

```
<template id="woa_website_sale_partner_product_tag.product" inherit_id="website_sale.product">
    <xpath expr="//div[@id='product_details']" position="after">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-xl-4 offset-xl-2" id="woa_website_sale_partner_product_tag.product.tag">
            <t t-if="request.env.user.active == True">
                <b>Your reference for this product:</b>
                <t t-if="product.woa_website_sale_partner_product_tag">
                    <span t-field="product.woa_website_sale_partner_product_tag"/>
                </t>
            </t>
        </div>
    </xpath>
</template>
```